# Datamapper fails when ampersand is in the XML input payload

Tags: xml, xslt, datamapper, wso2-esb

I have a simple XML payload with a repeating group of icpNo, CustName, Email, Mobile which I am transforming to CSV format.

The CustName has an ampersand in a few entries. For example:

```
Mr & Mrs Smith.
```

The DataMapper fails when trying to transform this. If I do not map this element the Datamapper this works fine.

I am sure it is the ampersand causing the problem because if I go into the dmc file and encode it using the javascript encodeURIComponent function it works. Of course, in my target I get the encoded values such as space and ampersand- which I do not want as I am producing a CSV file.

How can I get the Datamapper to transform XML containing ampersands and produce the CSV output with the ampersands in there in readable format (i.e not escaped)?  Or should I not use the Datamapper and use XSLT?

Attaching a sample input XML which is actually an output from DSS:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<Entry>
<icpNo>70</icpNo>
<customerNo>70</customerNo>
<surname>p&amp;p</surname>
<middleName>s&amp;s</middleName>
<firstname />
</Entry>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the exception that's thrown when this message is mapped using datamapper

```
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character ' ' (code 32); expected a semi-colon after the reference for entity 's'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [140,10]
    at com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException.throwLazily(WstxLazyException.java:45)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwLazyError(StreamScanner.java:720)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.safeFinishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.getText(BasicStreamReader.java:858)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXBuilder.createOMText(StAXBuilder.java:289)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXBuilder.createOMText(StAXBuilder.java:250)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:252)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.build(OMSerializableImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.detach(OMElementImpl.java:700)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.setParent(OMNodeImpl.java:105)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:212)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.addChild(SOAPBodyImpl.java:231)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(DataMapperMediator.java:340)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.mediate(DataMapperMediator.java:256)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:766)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please post some sample of what you have tried so far. You might get some help.

Comment: If your input contains an unescaped ampersand character, then it is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT. A proper XML document will have `Mr &amp; Mrs Smith`. -- Caveat: I know nothing about DataMapper.